# Node convert base64 svg file to base64 png file

Tags: javascript, node.js, svg, type-conversion, png

Is it possible to convert `base64` svg files to `base64` png files with `node`? I have only links for that files, I did not download them

Comment: Maybe look into an external library for image processing like [sharp](https://github.com/lovell/sharp).

Comment: @skara9 yes but they are using files on server side, I would like to do it without downloading any files or having them in the folder, just URLs

Comment: Well, you can't convert from svg to png without first downloading the svg.  So, now we're not sure what you're asking. And, in case you didn't realize, SVG is a vector-based format (think Adobe Illustrator) and png is a bitmap format (think Adobe Photoshop).  To convert SVG to PNG, you have to first have all the SVG, then render it to a specific size and resolution and then convert that render to a PNG bitmap.

Comment: Specific examples on  how to use the sharp library to download and convert an svg image here: https://sharp.pixelplumbing.com/api-constructor.  And, if you already have the svg in a local file, it's simpler as shown here: https://coderrocketfuel.com/article/convert-svg-to-png-using-node-js-and-sharp